# PHP Form - send selected info

Tags: php, html, forms

I'd like some help with a PHP form. The user on my form can select multiple products and amount of each products - I'm wondering, how can I make so that when the form is sent I can see what products and how much of each product the user has chosen in the mail?

The product list is in

and the amount is a select dropdown.

```
 <ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button">Product 1</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group checked-list-box">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button">Product 2</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Add names to your `select`s and then `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with php, could you give me a snippet or something.

The user can click on the Product 1 or Product 2, and select how many he wants of each and then click on the send button and the form is sent and I can see on the mail how much he wanted and what product he wanted.

Comment: there is nothing like a "PHP form" btw. you are talking about a "HTML form" which you want to use together with PHP scripts.

Comment: yea okey, i just need help with achieving this

Answer (score 4):

Add `name="amount[]"` to both/all selects

```
<select class="form-control" name="amount[PRODUCT_ID_GOES_THERE]">
<!-- eg. <select class="form-control" name="amount[<?php echo $product_id ?>]"> -->
```

and then you will have values from them in:

```
$_POST['amount'][24] // amount of product with ID=24
$_POST['amount'][2]  // amount of product with ID=2
```

Comment: Since I'll have many selects is there a way to limit them down, I need to know which select goes to what product if you understand what I mean.

Comment: so put product ID into select names, i updated my code. It supposed to have prouct id in `$product_id`. Or you can put IDs there manually, i don't know how you build your site.

Answer (score 0):

I really hope you are not building your product list by adding the same code over and over for each product.

There is a code approach called DRY, which means Don't Repeat Yourself. The benefit will come to you when you decide to make a change to the code and need to repeat that change multiple times.

Your code could look like this:

```
$my_products = array(
    '343' => 'Product 1',
    '4' => 'Product 2'
    ); // these values could be stored and retrieved from database

foreach ( $my_products as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<ul class=\"list-group checked-list-box\">";
      echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6\">";
        echo "<li class=\"list-group-item\" data-style=\"button\">$value</li>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<div class=\"col-xs-6\">";
        echo "<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"quantity[$key]>\"";
          for ( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        echo "</select>";
      echo "</div>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Now if you want to add products, all you need to do is add an id and name to the `$my_products` array. If you want to change the code, you only have to change it in one spot.

Comment: thank you mate, do you perhaps have kik or skype or something? i need help with this form and might be easier to chat